# Add subtitles to Ogg Video

Tags: dvd, encoding, ripping, subtitles, ogg

I've started to convert my DVD collection to Ogg Video (OGV) and it works so far quite good.
However, I heard that I can embed the subtitles inside the OGV-file as well.

How can I do this on Linux?

On Windows there are several applications but on Linux not so much.  Any examples would be appreciated.

*Edit:* I have the original VOB of course.

<sub>*PS. No, I don't give out my movies. Don't even ask. I paid for them, not you. :)*</sub>

Comment: Small suggestion: if your video players handle Matroska container, use it instead of OGV. You don't have to reencode movies, and some corner cases are handled better; f.e. subtitles encoding in OGV is not defined, and in Matroska it is always forced to be Unicode.

Answer (score 1):

I've used several subtitles editors on Linux: [gnome-subtitles](http://gnome-subtitles.sourceforge.net/), [Ksubtile](http://ksubtile.sourceforge.net/) and [KDVDAuthor](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dvdauthor-gui/) mostly. In all cases, I've kept my subtitles as `.srt` files and then added them to the DVD when authoring.

As for embedding subtitles in a video in `ogv`, [this link](http://git.xiph.org/?p=ffmpeg2theora.git;a=blob_plain;f=subtitles.txt;hb=HEAD) should probably help you.

Answer (score 1):

There is another related link: https://archive.flossmanuals.net/ogg-theora/subtitles/embedding-subtitles.html

Comment: `ffmpeg` still does not support ogv subtitles at the time being : https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/3039